# pymodbus: exception in modbus TCP

Tags: python-3.x, pymodbus

How can I generate an exception when the client writes a number out of range to my server? Also, I would like some vairables on my server to be read-only and other read / write. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 2):

Pymodbus generally handles out of bound register access internally, a request to read/write a data block which is out of range would raise `ExceptionResponse('Invalid Address'`) . On the client side , you can check if the received response is exception response by either checking `isError()` method on the response (pymodbus v1.5.0 and above).

Refer [synchronous_server](http://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/synchronous_server.html) and [synchronous_client](http://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/synchronous_client.html)

Also by default, Discrete Inputs and Input Registers are Read only and Holding registers and Coils and Read/Write. Any attempt to write to the read only datablocks raises an `ExceptionResponse`.
If you have specific requirements to make a range of holding registers/coils read only you can have a look at the various [datablocks](http://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/pymodbus.datastore.html#module-pymodbus.datastore.store) , to create a custom datablock refer [custom datablock example](http://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/custom_datablock.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer,
I have read about the exceptions of the pymodbus server, but I have not been able to implement it. I'm taking the example of updating server:

values = context[slave_id].getValues(register, address, count=10)

Comment: Is it possible to restrict a read-only modbus address on the server ???

Comment: The updating server has a block size of 100, any attempt to read values starting at offset `100` would throw an exemption response. Here is the client code for the reference.                                                                                    `>>> from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
>>> c = ModbusTcpClient(port=5020)
>>> c.read_holding_registers(100, 1, unit=1)
<pymodbus.pdu.ExceptionResponse object at 0x10e2dfc50>`